# Formula returns blank while showing result in tooltip

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple formula in my Google Spreadsheet calculating the start of the current week: =TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1

It was working perfectly, but a few days ago it began returning a blank cell. All the dependent formulas also show up as blank. At the same time, I can see the correct formula result in the tooltip:

[image: tooltip]

I have tried clearing cache and using other browsers, but it didn`t help. I also tried replacing the formula to calculate the start of the month (=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1) with no luck

Any idea how it can be fixed?

Comment: are you confident that the text is black? as opposed to white and therefore not being visible?

Comment: I have tested the function and it did return the date correctly. Have you checked on the previous comment suggestion or if there is anything formatting the cell and does not allow for the result to show?

Comment: I also see a filter icon hiding to the left there. If you've got some filter active, it's possible that the results of these formulas are being shown at the bottom of the sheet, underneath blank rows. Tough to say from a one-cell screenshot what might be going on. Consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), so that we have the full scope of information to work with.

Comment: @ErikTyler yes! it was the filter! thank you so much, you saved my day

Comment: Happy to hear it. I've added the comment as an actual post below. If you would, help us close out this post and issue by marking that post "Best Answer." Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a filter icon hiding to the left there. If you've got some filter active, it's possible that the results of these formulas are being shown at the bottom of the sheet, underneath blank rows.